# What is the keystroke to quickly change a file's name in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen friends quickly hit a key on the left side of the keyboard and then change the name of a file they had selected.

What is the keystroke to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's <kbd>F2</kbd> (Function 2).

Comment: Upvote for you!  Never knew that and wow what a handy feature!

Comment: Upvoted - sysadmin for 10 years and didn't know that!

Answer (score 11):

As palehorse said, it's <kbd>F2</kbd>. But there's more: <kbd>F2</kbd> is the general key to rename on Windows: works on Excel or Calc cells for example, to replace their content.

Comment: Very true, it works in many applications for renaming.